# How to extract a value of a string which is there in url

Tags: iphone, url

I have a URL and want to extract part of the string.

The URL is in a similar format to this: www.google.com?id=10&jkhsds=fg.php.

I want to extract the value of id. How would I do this?

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create an `NSURL` object, like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

You can use the methods of the `NSURL` object to get whatever you need, e.g. `scheme`, `host`,  `port`, `path`, and `query`.

See here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: i hav url like www.google.com?id=10&jkhsds=fg.php

i want to extract the value of id

Comment: [NSURL query] will give you "?id=10&jkhsds=fg.php", then you'll have to use NSString methods to do the rest.

Comment: how to pass parameters to this query method

Answer (score 1):

See the [NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).  Methods which are likely to be of interest to you include rangeOfString, componentsSeparatedByString, substringFromIndex, and substringToIndex

Answer (score 0):

You can access the string through the `absoluteString` property of the `NSURL` class. Then you can extract some parts from the string with methods like

```
- (NSString *)substringFromIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex;
- (NSString *)substringToIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex;
- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)aRange;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get exactly what you want from various properties of the NSURL class such as baseURL,host,path,query etc...

If your URL is an NSString you can create an NSURL with [NSURL URLWithString:string]